# How to comment on MATLAB variables

Tags: variables, matlab, comments, workspace

When I´m using MATLAB, sometimes I feel the need to make comments on some variables. I would like to save these comments inside these variables. So when I have to work with many variables in the workspace, and I forget the context of some of these variables I could read the comments I put in every one of them. So I would like to comment variables and keep the comments inside of them.

Comment: I have never heard of such thing in any programming language. Use descriptive variable names. Or you could use structures with fields myVar1.value and myVar1.descr

Comment: @Mikhail, I haven't heard of such thing either. But I think he is asking something like javadoc, when you write special kind of comment before a method, and if your IDE supports it, you can access the documentation just by hovering mouse on any method call. I think it is works for variables too.

Comment: I really don´t know "javadoc".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I'm of the opinion that the best (and easiest) approach would be to make your variables self-documenting by giving them descriptive names, there *is* actually a way for you to do what you want using the object-oriented aspects of MATLAB. Specifically, you can create a new class which subclasses a built-in class so that it has an additional property describing the variable.

In fact, there is [an example in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/built-in-subclasses-with-properties.html) that does *exactly* what you want. It creates a new class `ExtendDouble` that behaves just like a double except that it has a `DataString` property attached to it which describes the data in the variable. Using this subclass, you can do things like the following:

```
N = ExtendDouble(10,'The number of data points')
N = 
The number of data points
     10
```

and `N` could be used in expressions just as any double value would. Using this example subclass as a template, you could create "commented" versions of other built-in numeric classes, with the exception of [those you are not allowed to subclass](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/subclassing-matlab-built-in-classes.html) (`char`, `cell`, `struct`, and `function_handle`).

Of course, it should be noted that instead of using the `ExtendDouble` class like I did in the above example, I could instead define my variable like so:

```
nDataPoints = 10;
```

which makes the variable self-documenting, albeit with a little more typing needed. ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about declaring another variable for your comments?
example:

```
\>> num = 5;  
\>> numc = 'This is a number that contains 5';  
\>> whos  
...
```

This is my first post in StackOverflow. Thanks.

Comment: It´s a great first post! I like so much!

Answer (score 1):

A convenient way to solve this is to have a function that does the storing and displaying of comments for you, i.e. something like the function below that will pop open a dialog box if you call it with `comments('myVar')` to allow you to enter new (or read/update previous) comments to variable (or function, or co-worker) labeled `myVar`.

Note that the comments will not be available in your next Matlab session. To make this happen, you have to add save/load functionality to `comments` (i.e. every time you change anything, you write to a file, and any time you start the function and `database` is empty, you load the file if possible).

```
function comments(name)
%COMMENTS stores comments for a matlab session
% 
% comments(name) adds or updates a comment stored with the label "name"
%
% comments prints all the current comments

%# database is a n-by-2 cell array with {label, comment}
persistent database

%# check input and decide what to do
if nargin < 1 || isempty(name)
    printDatabase;
else
    updateDatabase;
end

    function printDatabase
        %# prints the database
        if isempty(database)
            fprintf('no comments stored yet\n')
        else
            for i=1:size(database,1)
                fprintf('%20s : %s\n',database{i,1},database{i,2});
            end
        end
    end
    function updateDatabase
        %# updates the database

        %# check whether there is already a comment 
        if size(database,1) > 0 && any(strcmp(name,database(:,1)))
            idx = strcmp(name,database(:,1));
            comment = database(idx,2);
        else
            idx = size(database,1)+1;
            comment = {''};
        end

        %# ask for new/updated comment
        comment = inputdlg(sprintf('please enter comment for %s',name),'add comment',...
            5,comment);

        if ~isempty(comment)
            database{idx,1} = name;
            database(idx,2) = comment;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

*Always* always always keep the Matlab editor open with a script documenting what you do. That is, variable assignments and calculations.

Only exceptions are very short sessions where you want to experiment. Once you have something -- add it to the file (It's also easier to cut and paste when you can see your entire history).

This way you can always start over. Just `clear all` and rerun the script. You never have random temporaries floating around in your workspace.

Eventually, when you are finished, you will also have something that is close to 'deliverable'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using structures (or cells, although structures would require extra memory use)?

'>> dataset1.numerical=5;

'>> dataset1.comment='This is the dataset that contains 5';

```
 dataset1 = 
   numerical: 5
   comment: 'This is the dataset that contains 5'
```

Comment: It´s good too, but What about functions? Usually function works well with this type of data?

Comment: Hi Peterstone, how about the followings: data.x=1:10; func.f1='sin(data.x)'; plot(data.x,eval(func.f1))